# Converting routes for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This is a pretty silly question but I'm having some real trouble figuring out.  I want to convert the following routes to make it compliant for Rails 3 (from 2.8.x):

```
map.with_options :controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'show' do |static_page|
      static_page.faq 'faq', :id => 'faq'
      static_page.about 'about', :id => 'about'
      static_page.blog 'blog', :id => 'blog'
      static_page.support 'support', :id => 'support'
      static_page.privacy 'privacy', :id => 'privacy'
      static_page.howitworks 'howitworks', :id => 'howitworks'
      static_page.contact 'contact', :id => 'contact'
      static_page.terms_and_conditions 'terms_and_conditions', :id => 'terms_and_conditions'
  end
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do it like this:

```
  scope '/static_pages', :name_prefix => 'static_page', :to => 'static_pages#show' do
    for page in %w{ faq about blog support privacy howitworks contact terms_and_conditions }
      match page, :id => page
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is awesome, I just wrote an article about this a couple weeks ago:

[Routing in Ruby on Rails 3](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/02/routing-in-ruby-on-rails-3/)

It goes over most aspects of the conversion, with a downloadable sample app.  While I didn't cover the `with_options` conversion specifically, I can do a little of that here.  Here's a short way:

```
scope :static_pages, :name_prefix => "static_page" do
  match "/:action", :as => "action"
end
```

This matches all the routes you have above, and your named routes would look like this:

```
static_page_path(:faq)
static_page_path(:about)
```

...and so on.  If you want your named routes to still look like `static_page_faq_path` then you can specify them one at at time, like so:

```
scope '/static_pages', :name_prefix => 'static_page' do
  match '/faq', :to => 'static_pages#faq'
  match '/about', :to => 'static_pages#about'
  # fill in all the rest here
end
```

I hope this helps!